# Find Forward Vector Based on Camera Location

Tags: ios, vector, quaternions

For the project I am working on, I am attempting to allow the user to rotate a cube based on the direction they swipe on the screen. I have this working except for the direction that the cube rotates in.

For example, my forward vector starts at ( 0, 0, -1 ). However, once I rotate the cube 90 degrees in a direction, the forward vector changes. This is what I expect to happen but creates a challenge for what I am doing.

I have the code set to determine which way the cameras direction is by checking the checks the cameras forward like so...

```
GLKVector3 forward = [ m_camera getForwardVector ];
if ( fabsf( forward.x ) > fabsf( forward.z ) ) {
    // Need forward vector to be in x-direction
    // Rotate cube around axis ( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
} else {
    // Need forward vector to be in z-direction
    // Rotate cube around axis ( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
}
```

What I want to do is to rotate the cube around the specified axis. However, after the cube is rotated multiple times, the vectors positions are not the same as the world positions so it does not rotate correctly due to the changed vector positions.

My cubes rotation is stored in a quaternion. So is there a way to determine which vector is the "forward" vector based on where the camera is looking?

Here is my rotate code if that helps at all. Thanks!

```
- ( void ) rotate: ( GLKVector3 ) axis withAngle: ( GLfloat ) angle {
    [ self rotate: GLKQuaternionMakeWithAngleAndVector3Axis( GLKMathDegreesToRadians( angle ), axis ) ];
}

- ( void ) rotate: ( GLKQuaternion ) quat {
    m_rotation = GLKQuaternionNormalize( GLKQuaternionMultiply( m_rotation, quat ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after reading a lot of things around StackOverflow, I came up with a solution for my problem and I want to share it in case anyone else is struggling.

I was on the correct track but just had to make some minor changes. First was in the rotate method. In mine, I was rotating around my objects local axis. I changed it to rotate around the world axis like so.

```
- ( void ) rotate: ( GLKVector3 ) axis withAngle: ( GLfloat ) angle {
    // THIS WILL ROTATE AROUND THE WORLD AXIS
    m_rotation = GLKQuaternionMultiply( GLKQuaternionMakeWithAngleAndAxis( GLKMathDegreesToRadians( angle ), axis.x, axis.y, axis.z ), m_rotation );


    // THIS WILL ROTATE AROUD THE LOCAL AXIS
    // m_rotation = GLKQuaternionMultiply( m_rotation, GLKQuaternionMakeWithAngleAndAxis( GLKMathDegreesToRadians( angle ), axis.x, axis.y, axis.z ) );
}
```

Now, I could rotate around the world axis. Then when I was rotating I could use the forward vector like so.

```
GLKVector3 forward = [ m_camera getCurrentViewPosition ];
if ( fabsf( forward.x ) > fabs( forward.z ) ) {
    m_rotateZ = ( forward.x < 0 ) ? -ROTATION_AMOUNT : ROTATION_AMOUNT;
    m_shouldRotateZ = true;
} else {
    m_rotateX = ( forward.z < 0 ) ? ROTATION_AMOUNT : -ROTATION_AMOUNT;
    m_shouldRotateX = true;
}
m_totalRotation = 0;
```

I checked the length of the vector components. Where x was longer, the forward vector was in the x direction so I could rotate around my z axis.

I hope this clears some stuff up and possibly helps someone in the future. If you have any questions feel free to leave a comment and I will help clear some more stuff up.